# What is the difference between “we might be seeing” and “we might see”?

Tags: continuous-aspect

I have noted that when something unprecedented is coming, the phrase *we might be seeing something* is frequently used. E.g.

> We might be seeing yet another crisis soon.

Is there any difference between this form and the simple *we might see*?

During my short research it seemed to me that both are used for simple future with a degree of probability.

Comment: One of your versions uses a progressive aspect construction ("be seeing") and involves the future. And so, you might be interested in the topic of *the progressive futurate*. (One possible difference between your two examples is that the progressive version tends to be used for the relatively near future.)

Comment: Also, another possible difference is that, for me, the version with the progressive ("be seeing") is sorta emphasizing the aspectuality of a possible future situation, with an interpretation like: *We might soon be in the* **middle** *of another crisis*. While the other version is providing more of a perfective interpretation of a possible future situation, and is not really concerned with the internal states or progression within that situation: *Soon another crisis might come (and then go)*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

For many contexts, the two terms seem interchangeable, but my sense is that we prefer to use them under slightly different circumstances.

I take *we might see* to ideally express the possibility of using the faculty of sight to apprehend the object at some point in the future.

> We might see lions on the safari.

To word the point simply, the lions are already there and the question is whether we will see it.

I take *we might be seeing* to reflect that the occurrence has not yet happened and this is why we are speaking in terms of probabilities:

> We might be seeing a recession in the future.

The question is not whether or not we can see the recession if it is there. Instead, it is whether or not we will have a recession which we would then see. So we could say this means roughly the same as *Were a recession to occur we would witness its consequences*

But again we could definitely say:

> We might see a recession in the next five years due to the tax policies of X.

and this would function with the same meaning as the above example.

I think adding the progressive modal expresses a lower degree of probability than the active modal statement and/or that the active modal relates to the successful use of the verb that follows in a more direct sense.

Thus,

> We might be seeing lions on the safari

sounds like one is hinting at something more than the direct modal.

Comment: I think this is a great answer, but leaves out one possible usage for "we might be seeing". You could also use it to speculate about a trend or change that is unclear, such as:

"We might be seeing the beginning of a recession."

Comment: Could you explain more about what "*the passive modal*" is in the OP's examples?

Comment: @F.E. passive modal = we might be seeing (might = modal / be seeing = passive progressive)

Comment: So you consider "be seeing" as a *passive progressive*? But isn't that actually in active voice?

Comment: I realized while I was out that you are correct -- that's not a passive tense.